# JPA component in camel cannot reconnect automatically to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, apache-camel

When I reboot my database while my application is running, **JPA components** cannot reconnect automatically.

```
2017-02-09 17:45:08,400 ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper(131) - Connection closed. - [Camel (camel-1) thread #99 - jpa://com.toto.Toto  ]
```

**But still** I am able to execute SQL request with spring-data in my CXF routes.

My datasource definition in context.xml :

```
<!-- JDBC connection -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/oracle"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="toto"
            password="toto"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@toto:1568:SID"
            maxTotal="100"
            maxIdle="10"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            validationQuery="select 1 from dual"/>
```

And here is what my JPA component looks like :

```
    @Component
public class TotoPollerRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  private final String uri;

  private static final String POLLING_REQUEST = "select tt from Toto tt where tt.key = 1";

  public TotoPollerRoute() {
    super();
    final StringBuilder uriBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    uriBuilder.append("jpa://");
    uriBuilder.append(TotoPollerRoute.class.getName());
    uriBuilder.append("?");
    uriBuilder.append("consumeDelete=false");
    uriBuilder.append("&consumeLockEntity=true");
    uriBuilder.append("&consumer.SkipLockedEntity=true");
    uriBuilder.append("&maximumResults=10");
    uriBuilder.append("&consumer.query=");
    uriBuilder.append(POLLING_REQUEST);
    this.uri = uriBuilder.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    // @formatter:off
    from(uri)
        .to("TotoMainRoute");
    // @formatter:on
  }
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some deep debugging I finally figured out my JPA components weren't using the EntityManagerFactory declared in the Spring context.

Two ways to solve that :

1. Modify the JPA uri on each JPA component and add the sharedEntityManager option :

   ```
   private final String uri = "jpa://TotoPollerRoute?consumeDelete=false"
       + "&consumeLockEntity=true"
       + "&consumer.SkipLockedEntity=true"
       + "&maximumResults=10"
       + "&sharedEntityManager=true"
       + "&joinTransaction=false"
       + "&consumer.query=select tt from Toto tt where tt.key = 1";
   ```
2. Instanciate JPA component in Spring :

   ```
   @Bean
   public JpaComponent jpa() {
       final JpaComponent jpa = new JpaComponent();
       jpa.setSharedEntityManager(true);
       jpa.setJoinTransaction(false);
       return jpa;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks..It Worked

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the following attributes

- `validationInternal="30000"`
- `testWhileIdle="true"`
- `testOnReturn="false"`

In addition to the following which you have declared:

- `testOnBorrow="true"`
- `validationQuery="select 1 from dual"`

Comment: Still not enough, I have the same behaviour.
While restarting my DB I get the following errors in that order :
`2017-02-10 10:58:00,366 ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper(131) - ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress`

`2017-02-10 10:58:05,615 ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper(131) - No more data to read from socket - [Camel (camel-1) thread #10 - jpa://com.`

`2017-02-10 10:58:30,339 ERROR o.h.e.j.spi.SqlExceptionHelper(131) - Closed Connection - [Camel (camel-1) thread #59 - jpa://com.`

Comment: So camel is keeping the connection open in-between polls perhaps?  You might want to consult the camel documentation then.

Comment: In fact, if not specified camel instanciate its own EntityManagerFactory for JPA component. I finally figured out it wasn't using the one I declared in my spring context.