# Apache Camel JPA Thread Hung

Tags: java, apache-camel, datasource, camel-jpa

I have created one route using Java DSL which has JPA component to poll the records from DB periodically. it is working good. I hope each route has one worker thread. if DB is down or any N/W issue for minute, route is not working as expected. application is running.( it is not polling records from DB even after DB or N/W is up ). I think worker thread got hung and route is not working.

```
SimpleRegistry registry = new SimpleRegistry(); 
registry.put("datasource",myDataSourceObj);
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(registry); 
context.addRoutes(new myRouteBuilder()); 

from URI= "uri="jpa://br.rafaeltuelho.model.Customer?consumer.namedQuery=Customer.findAll&amp;consumer.delay=30000&amp;consumeDelete=true"
```

please anybody help me to fix this issue.
 How to avoid this worker thread hung ? 
 How to restart the worker thread once N/W or DB is up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding 2 params in JPA URI . it is working good after DB is up.

```
+ "&sharedEntityManager=true"
+ "&joinTransaction=false"
```

**[JPA component in camel cannot reconnect automatically to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143914/jpa-component-in-camel-cannot-reconnect-automatically-to-database#)**